# Javascript/jQuery: display key and value to JSON representation from input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I am having trouble displaying a dynamic key and value to a toJSON string.

This is what I have:

```
var element = $(this),
    settings = $.extend({
        color: "#556b2f",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        textSize: "25%",
        toJsonPath: "",
        objectPropertyName: null,
        appendtoJsonElement: "#outputJson",
        hiddenInputField: $('input[name="hiddenField"]'),
        tempInputField: $('<input name="temp" type="text" />')
    }, options),

    toJson = function(textValue){
    var path = settings.toJsonPath;
    var $ElOutput = settings.appendtoJsonElement;

    var key = settings.hiddenInputField.attr("name");
    var value = textValue; 
    var object = key[value];

    if (object){

        path.push(object);
        $($ElOutput).html(JSON.stringify(path, null, '\t'));
    }
    else {
        path.push(textValue);
        $($ElOutput).html(JSON.stringify(path, null, '\t'));
    }
```

I want to have a data-title attribute in the input tag where I can specify the 'key'. right now I am using the name attribute as the 'key'. The 'textvalue' variable will be the value.

so:

"key": "value"

Right now I get the value displayed in quotes. I need both to complete JSON.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may have to be more specific. Maybe provide input and expected output with a test of the output (which will likely fail until you get your answer). Try using static strings everywhere you can (as we cannot see what your input element has).

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = {};

// Take selectors
$('input').each(function (){ 
    json[$(this).data('title')] = $(this).val();
});
```